# What is wrong with this media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I would be much obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me why this media query only works partially (the font size changes but not the color).

```
<div>
<span id='one'>This is one 
<span id='two'>and this is two</span>
 and now back in one</span>
</div>

@media all and (min-width:500px)
{
 #two{font-size:2em;color:#0000ff;text-decoration:underline;}
}

#two{color:red;}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67ZL8/1/) showing the problem in action.  Just drag the resize bar to adjust the size of the output window.  The font size changes as expected but the color stays put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `#two{color:red;}` overrides the style in the `media query` because you put it **after** the `media query`. Put it **before** - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67ZL8/2/)

Comment: Thanks.  May be I am working too hard but that gave me an "I am an idiot" moment.  I'll accept your answer just as soon as the system permits!

Comment: This is the right answer. In practice to use CSS we have to write `@media` after our all CSS Styles. Vote Up

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
#two{color:red;}

@media all and (min-width:500px){
    #two{
        font-size:2em;
        color:green;
        text-decoration:underline
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi maneesh, it's always better to answer with more than just code. Try giving an explanation why it behaves like this.